# cl.exe not generating functions that can be accessed externally

Tags: c, windows, cl

I tried building an add function as a library with Microsoft's cl.exe, but none of the functions are able to be accessed externally. I also tried adding the Extern "C" in the header with this from another post:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

EXTERNC int add(int a, int b);
```

Build script:

```
cl /LD add.c
```

[Built binary in Dependency Walker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alqmv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export a function you need to use [`__declspec(dllexport)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=msvc-170) or a [.def](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-def-files?view=msvc-170) file.

```
__declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```